# Protocol Buffer with java in windows

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm using protocol buffer for my first time and I don't know how to compile my *.proto file and how to integrate it with my project in eclipse, any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to download the protocol buffers compiler.

then run `protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --java_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/example.proto`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment but how can run this command in windows?

Comment: did you download https://protobuf.googlecode.com/svn/rc/protoc-2.6.0-win32.zip ?

Comment: yes but when I open protoc.exe I have message "Missing file"